# Suddenly one of my apps not sending notifications at all

Tags: parse-platform

I have about 5 apps that using Parse.com as push notification , 
Suddenly 1 of my apps (Android) stop sending notifications how ever it shows the green tick that notification sent successfully but when check pushes sent it shows Blank or 0 I didn't update the app or do anything to it, checked that I didn't exceed the 1,000,000 free push notifications yet
and it's only on 1 app , others working fine

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify if your app is on Anroid or iOS.

Assuming it's iOS - check that your APS certificate has not expired. The APS certificate is valid for a single year, and it does not automatically renew itself.

Comment: Sorry , it's Android created on July